# Spring Boot, Spring Data JPA, CrudRepository, file based read only database packaged in JAR

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-boot, h2

I wrote an application using Spring Boot, Spring Data JPA and h2 file based database. All works just fine effortlessly... Thanks Spring.

Now I try to deliver some system data in another read only h2 file based database. It's possible to package my "system.db" in the JAR and access it with Spring Data JPA?

How configure my "system dataSource" and how structure my code... Always effortless?

I have:

1) my.package.app.Application

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new SpringApplication(Application.class).run(args);
    }
}
```

2) my.package.app.repo the root package of my repositories (CrudRepository)

3) config/application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:h2:file:~/MyApp/data/default
spring.datasource.username: sa
spring.datasource.password: sa
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: validate
```